# how to break out of a for loop in lua

Tags: for-loop, lua

i have the following code:

```
  for k, v in pairs(temptable) do
         if string.match(k,'doe') then 
              if v["name"] == var2 then
                     txterr =  "Invalid name for "..k
                     duplicate = true
             end
             if duplicate then
                     break
             end
         end
    end
```

when duplicate is set to true, i want to exit the for loop all together. right now, it just loops through all the values in the table even if it finds a match.

i tried using the break statement but i think it is breaking out of the "if" statement.

i was thinking about a do while loop i could wrap around the entire for loop but i would still need a way to break out of the for.

thanks.

Comment: The way you use `break` is correct so the problem is not in this part of the code. Post more context (content of `temptable`, is `duplicate` defined somewhere?, etc).

Comment: `even if it finds a match` have you added some `print` statements to see what is hit, i.e: a `print "duplicate found"` into the `if v["name"] == var2 then` and another `print "duplicate is true"` into the `if duplicate then` and see if it ever hits them? Could you also post `temptable` so we can see what it contains?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tried the following:

```
temptable = {a=1, doe1={name=1}, doe2={name=2}, doe3={name=2}}
var2 = 1
for k, v in pairs(temptable) do
    print('trying', k)
    if string.match(k,'doe') then 
        print('match doe', k, v.name, var2)
        if v["name"] == var2 then
            txterr =  "Invalid name for "..k
            duplicate = true
            print('found at k=', k)
        end
        if duplicate then
            print('breaking')
            break
        end
    end
end
```

and it works:

```
trying  doe2
match doe   doe2    2   1
trying  doe1
match doe   doe1    1   1
found at k= doe1
breaking
```

As you can see it skipped a and doe3. The error is therefore elsewhere: var2 or your names are not what you think (like the name values are strings whereas var2 is number), or you don't have any keys that match.